# Can i initialize static readonly class field with process.env.FOO in Express using Typescript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, express

Is it possible to initialize static readonly class field with env variable in Express using Typescript? I use `.env` file.

My code currently looks like this:

```
class Foo {
  private static readonly port: number = process.env.PORT!;

  public static getStaticPort() {
    return this.port; // undefined
  }

  public static getProcessPort() {
    return process.env.PORT; // 42
  }
}
```

When i call `Foo.getStaticPort()` it gives me undefined.

Comment: You should not have any problems with this code. Try removing all code irrelevant to the problem, and see if the error persists